# Java: A FileInputStream that blocks in read() while other thread downloads remainder of file?

Tags: java, io, inputstream

I have an FFmpeg-based video-playing app which is able to play content from any arbitrary InputStream.

It is important that the app is able to play a video file which is in the process of being downloaded. What I seem to need for this is a special kind of FileInputStream that will (a) share file access with the downloading thread, and (b) if it reaches the end of the downloaded portion, will quietly block until more content becomes available.

(a) seems easy enough thanks to RandomAccessFile, but I'm a bit puzzled about (b). I can probably hack something up that will work, but I am wondering if there's a standard approach to implementing this. Thinking about it in detail gives me a feeling that I may be missing something obvious.

Any thoughts? How would you guys do this?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure, I think so. A quick glance at my code for the app concerned shows that I created a "RandomAccessFileInputStream" class which extends a plain old InputStream and which contains a RandomAccessFile opened in "rw" mode. That's the stream used by the video player, and it appears to be able to peacefully coexist with a downloader that writes to the same file via a separate file handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is no real answer to this question. I've got something which works, but it looks like inelegant hacking to me. Perhaps sometimes that's inevitable.

Answer (score 2):

If you can push the data not in the file but into a OutputStream (or maybe write simulataneously to both FileOutputStream and other shared PipedOutputStream), this would be the easiest solution:

Use [PipedOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html) and [PipedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html). This will allow you to implement both A and B, however you will need to somehow implement video buffering on the viewer side.

Basically your downloader thread will write every bit of data it gets to the PipedOutputStream. The `write()` method is not blocking, as the data is pushed to the internal buffer of the pipe.

Your viewer thread will simply `read()` from the pipedInputStream, as here is what the API says: `This method blocks until input data is available, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown.`

Comment: Wouldn't this require having a buffer that could end up needing to be nearly as large as the entire video file?

Comment: No, after the data is read from the pipe - it is removed from the buffer. So unless your View thread crashes, pipe buffer will only contain downloaded but not yet read data. If you are talking about the buffering I mentioned that you'd need to implement, it should be static size of minimal block you want to show to user. For example 5 seconds of video. Otherwise on a sluggish connection watching the video will be a horrible experience.

Answer (score 0):

You have to poll the length of the file.  There is no way to block waiting for the length of the file to change using the file alone. You can busy poll, or poll every 10 or 100 ms.

If the writer and reader are in the same process, you can use locking/synchronized blocks to notify the reader when more data has been added.

With multiple processes, you could use a socket to either send the data, or at least notify when the length has changed allowing the reader to block.

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not control the download process, and want to play just ANY downloading file (even by some other downloaders) then you can [Watch directory for changes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html).

It needs to be mentioned that this method is cross-platform and cross-filesystem. Here's quote from the same article:

> > Most file system implementations have native support for file change notification. The Watch Service API takes advantage of this support where available. However, when a file system does not support this mechanism, the Watch Service will poll the file system, waiting for events.